# ¿Cómo optimizar lectura e inserción desde Excel a MySQL con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

El excel que leo y del cual inserto los datos, tiene 55 columnas igual que la tabla MySql. Al final, para poder acelerar, he estado probando entrelo que me habéis dicho y buscando más cosas y probando y probando, y esto me ha funcionado, tanto para subir el excel, leerlo, insertar sin problemas de caractéres. Lo pongo como respuesta, pero si alguien pudiera decirme como mejorar el tiempo de ejecución de este "ladrillo" lo agradezco, pues cuando lleva 2.000 filas insertadas de las 7.000 del excel, me da un 504 el nginx. Aparte, ¿alguna idea de como poner un "loading" mientras se ejecuta la inserción?. Aquí el ladrillo de código que uso:

```
<?php
include('dbconect.php');
require_once('vendor/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
require_once('vendor/SpreadsheetReader.php');

if (isset($_POST["import"]))
{
    
$allowedFileType = ['application/vnd.ms-excel','text/xls','text/xlsx','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'];
  
  if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"],$allowedFileType)){

        $targetPath = 'subidas/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);
        
        $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($targetPath);
        
        $sheetCount = count($Reader->sheets());
        for($i=0;$i<$sheetCount;$i++)
        {
            
            $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);
            
            foreach ($Reader as $Row)
            {
          
                $c1 = "";
                if(isset($Row[0])) {
                    $c1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[0]);
                }
                
                $c2 = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $c2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[1]);
                }
                
                $c3 = "";
                if(isset($Row[2])) {
                    $c3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[2]);
                }
                
                $c4 = "";
                if(isset($Row[3])) {
                    $c4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[3]);
                }
                 $c5 = "";
                if(isset($Row[4])) {
                    $c5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[4]);
                }
                 $c6 = "";
                if(isset($Row[5])) {
                    $c6 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[5]);
                }
                 $c7 = "";
                if(isset($Row[6])) {
                    $c7 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[6]);
                }
                 $c8 = "";
                if(isset($Row[7])) {
                    $c8 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[7]);
                }
                 $c9 = "";
                if(isset($Row[8])) {
                    $c9 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[8]);
                }
                 $c10 = "";
                if(isset($Row[9])) {
                    $c10 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[9]);
                }
                 $c11 = "";
                if(isset($Row[10])) {
                    $c11 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[10]);
                }
                 $c12 = "";
                if(isset($Row[11])) {
                    $c12 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[11]);
                }
                 $c13 = "";
                if(isset($Row[12])) {
                    $c13 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[12]);
                }
                 $c14 = "";
                if(isset($Row[13])) {
                    $c14 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[13]);
                }
                 $c15 = "";
                if(isset($Row[14])) {
                    $c15 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[14]);
                }
                 $c16 = "";
                if(isset($Row[15])) {
                    $c16 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[15]);
                }
                
                $c17 = "";
                if(isset($Row[16])) {
                    $c17 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[16]);
                }
                 $c18 = "";
                if(isset($Row[17])) {
                    $c18 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[17]);
                }
                 $c19 = "";
                if(isset($Row[18])) {
                    $c19 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[18]);
                }
                 $c20 = "";
                if(isset($Row[19])) {
                    $c20 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[19]);
                }
                 $c21 = "";
                if(isset($Row[20])) {
                    $c21 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[20]);
                }
                 $c22 = "";
                if(isset($Row[21])) {
                    $c22 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[21]);
                }
                 $c23 = "";
                if(isset($Row[22])) {
                    $c23 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[22]);
                }
                 $c24 = "";
                if(isset($Row[23])) {
                    $c24 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[23]);
                }
                $c25 = "";
                if(isset($Row[24])) {
                    $c25 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[24]);
                }
                 $c26 = "";
                if(isset($Row[25])) {
                    $c26 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[25]);
                }
                 $c27 = "";
                if(isset($Row[26])) {
                    $c27 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[26]);
                }
                $c28 = "";
                if(isset($Row[27])) {
                    $c28 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[27]);
                }
                $c29 = "";
                if(isset($Row[28])) {
                    $c29 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[28]);
                }
                 $c30 = "";
                if(isset($Row[29])) {
                    $c30 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[29]);
                }
                 $c31 = "";
                if(isset($Row[30])) {
                    $c31 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[30]);
                }
                $c32 = "";
                if(isset($Row[31])) {
                    $c32 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[31]);
                }
                $c33 = "";
                if(isset($Row[32])) {
                    $c33 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[32]);
                }
                 $c34 = "";
                if(isset($Row[33])) {
                    $c34 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[33]);
                }
                 $c35 = "";
                if(isset($Row[34])) {
                    $c35 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[34]);
                }
                 $c36 = "";
                if(isset($Row[35])) {
                    $c36 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[35]);
                }
                 $c37 = "";
                if(isset($Row[36])) {
                    $c37 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[36]);
                }
                 $c38 = "";
                if(isset($Row[37])) {
                    $c38 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[37]);
                }
                 $c39 = "";
                if(isset($Row[38])) {
                    $c39 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[38]);
                }
                 $c40 = "";
                if(isset($Row[39])) {
                    $c40 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[39]);
                }
                $c41 = "";
                if(isset($Row[40])) {
                    $c41 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[40]);
                }
                 $c42 = "";
                if(isset($Row[41])) {
                    $c42 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[41]);
                }
                 $c43 = "";
                if(isset($Row[42])) {
                    $c43 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[42]);
                }
                 $c44 = "";
                if(isset($Row[43])) {
                    $c44 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[43]);
                }
                 $c45 = "";
                if(isset($Row[44])) {
                    $c45 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[44]);
                }
                 $c46 = "";
                if(isset($Row[45])) {
                    $c46 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[45]);
                }
                 $c47 = "";
                if(isset($Row[46])) {
                    $c47 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[46]);
                }
                 $c48 = "";
                if(isset($Row[47])) {
                    $c48 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[47]);
                }
                 $c49 = "";
                if(isset($Row[48])) {
                    $c49 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[48]);
                }
                 $c50 = "";
                if(isset($Row[49])) {
                    $c50 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[49]);
                }
                 $c51 = "";
                if(isset($Row[50])) {
                    $c51 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[50]);
                }
                 $c52 = "";
                if(isset($Row[51])) {
                    $c52 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[51]);
                }
                 $c53 = "";
                if(isset($Row[52])) {
                    $c53 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[52]);
                }
                 $c54 = "";
                if(isset($Row[53])) {
                    $c54 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[53]);
                }
                 $c55 = "";
                if(isset($Row[54])) {
                    $c55 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[54]);
                }
                
                
                if (!empty($c1) || !empty($c2) || !empty($c3) || !empty($c4) || !empty($c5) || !empty($c6) || !empty($c7) || !empty($c8) || !empty($c9)
                  || !empty($c10) || !empty($c11) || !empty($c12) || !empty($c13) || !empty($c14) || !empty($c15) || !empty($c16)
                  || !empty($c17) || !empty($c18) || !empty($c19) || !empty($c20) || !empty($c21) || !empty($c22) || !empty($c23)
                  || !empty($c24) || !empty($c25) || !empty($c26) || !empty($c27) || !empty($c28) || !empty($c29) || !empty($c30) || !empty($c31)
                   || !empty($c32) || !empty($c33) || !empty($c34) || !empty($c35) || !empty($c36) || !empty($c37) || !empty($c38) || !empty($c39) || !empty($c40)
                    || !empty($c41) || !empty($c42) || !empty($c43) || !empty($c44) || !empty($c45) || !empty($c46) || !empty($c47) || !empty($c48) || !empty($c49) || !empty($c50)
                     || !empty($c51) || !empty($c52) || !empty($c53) || !empty($c54) || !empty($c55)
                     
                     ) {
                   
                    $query = "INSERT INTO tabla_c50(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17,c18,c19,c20,c21,c22,c23,c24,c25,c26,c27,c28,c29,c30,
                    c31,c32,c33,c34,c35,c36,c37,c38,c39,c40,c41,c42,c43,c44,c45,c46,c47,c48,c49,c50.c51.c52,c53,c54,c55)
                        
                        values('".$c1."','".$c2."','".$c3."','".$c4."','".$c5."','".$c6."','".$c7."','".$c8."','".$c9."'
                        ,'".$c10."','".$c11."','".$c12."','".$c13."','".$c14."','".$c15."','".$c16."'
                        ,'".$c17."','".$c18."','".$c19."','".$c20."','".$c21."','".$c22."','".$c23."','".$c24."','".$c25."','".$c26."'
                        ,'".$c27."','".$c28."','".$c29."','".$c30."','".$c31."'
                        ,'".$c32."','".$c33."','".$c34."','".$c35."','".$c36."','".$c37."','".$c38."','".$c39."','".$c40."'
                        ,'".$c41."','".$c42."','".$c43."','".$c44."','".$c45."','".$c46."','".$c47."','".$c48."','".$c49."'
                        ,'".$c50."','".$c51."','".$c52."','".$c53."','".$c54."','".$c55."')";
                        
                        
                        
                    $resultados = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                    
                    if (! empty($resultados)) {
                        $type = "success";
                        $message = "Excel importado correctamente";
                    } else {
                        $type = "error";
                        $message = "Hubo un problema al importar registros";
                    }
                }
             }
        
         }
  }
  else
  { 
        $type = "error";
        $message = "El archivo enviado es invalido. Por favor vuelva a intentarlo";
  }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
<title></title>


<link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="assets/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
<header> 
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Importar Datos</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Importar<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="container">
  <h3 class="mt-5">Importar archivo Excel</h3>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12"> 
      <!-- Contenido -->
    
    <div class="outer-container">
        <form action="" method="post"
            name="frmExcelImport" id="frmExcelImport" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
                <label>Seleccionar Archivo Excel</label> <input type="file" name="file"
                    id="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx">
                <button type="submit" id="submit" name="import"
                    class="btn-submit">Importar Registros</button>
        
            </div>
        
        </form>
        
    </div>
    <div id="response" class="<?php if(!empty($type)) { echo $type . " display-block"; } ?>"><?php if(!empty($message)) { echo $message; } ?></div>
        <!-- Fin Contenido --> 
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container"> <span class="text-muted">
    <p> 2021</p>
    </span> </div>
</footer>
<script src="assets/jquery-1.12.4-jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A simple vista, y sin conocer el contexto, algunas recomendaciones: 1. Si usas consultas preparadas optimizas el código y le das seguridad, ahorrándote de paso todos los `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Una de las ventajas de las consultas preparadas es que son más rápidas cuando se ejecutan varias veces. 2. ¿Usas dos librerías de Excel distintas? No sé que tan eficiente sea la librería que usas para leer tus archivos... de todos modos, en vez de un Excel yo pensaría en algo más ligero, como un `.csv` por ejemplo. 3. Si son demasiados registros, puede que la optimización ...

Comment: ... deba estar a otro nivel. Si debes mantenerla desde PHP por algún motivo, debes pensar seriamente en paginar las inserciones para hacerlas por lotes. Lo ideal sería programar esto a un nivel más bajo, por ejemplo directamente en consola, y si el cliente necesita interactuar de alguna forma con el proceso de inserción, buscar una forma de informarle, mientras el proceso se realiza, a bajo nivel. Allí todo iría más rápido, porque las operaciones se realizan sin intermediarios (en este caso PHP, librerías para leer Excel, etc).

Comment: Gracias @A. Cedano. Estoy empezando en esto, y hay cosas qu eno entiendo aún. Cuando te refieres a consultas preparadas para ahorrar los escape, ¿podrías darme algún ejemplo por favor? ¡Gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: Implementar consultas preparadas significará replantear gran parte de tu código. Sugiero que leas sobre el tema, tanto en la documentación de PHP, como aquí mismo, pues ya ha varias preguntas / respuestas sobre el tema. Ver por ejemplo sobre [mysqli y consultas preparadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=mysqli%20consultas%20preparadas) o sobre [consultas preparadas en general](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=consultas%20preparadas).

Comment: Hola @A. Cedano, gracias por la respuesta. Estoy revisando todo lo que encuentro, pero como te digo, soy nuevo en esto y no logro asociar los ejemplos que veo a lo que necesitaría cambiar en mi código para optimizar. Curiosamente, de las 7.000 filas, siempre da el error 504 Gateway Time-Out cuando lleva 2.000 - 2.020. Gracias

Comment: [En la documentación](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-files/#combining-read-filters-with-the-setsheetindex-method-to-split-a-large-csv-file-across-multiple-worksheets) de `PhpSpreadsheet` hay una explicación sobre la clase `ChunkReadFilter`, que te permite leer el archivo por lotes de filas (2,000 filas por ejemplo), e ir haciendo las inserciones por lotes. También, si conviertes el Excel a .csv quedará en un formato más ligero y podrás igualmente insertarlo por lotes. En este caso no necesitarás pasar por librerías de terceros, podrías usar código propio de PHP.

Comment: Con un .csv podrías incluso hacer la inserción mediante [`LOAD DATA` de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html), que es **20 veces más rápido que `INSERT INTO`** [según el Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-optimization.html).